# Using google translate api in .net winform

Tags: .net, winforms, google-translate

**I'm trying to use Google translation api for .net in winforms:**

```
string DWord = "mesa";
TranslateClient Dclient = new TranslateClient("http://www.XXXXX.com");
//Dclient.ApiKey = "YYYYY";
//Dclient.UserIP = "ZZZZZ";
string translated = Dclient.Translate(DWord, "es", "en");
MessageBox.Show("Translation: " + translated);
Console.WriteLine(translated);
```

I get this error message:
[response status:403]Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

I already opened the Google account and gave my credit card info... but these 2 lines gave compiler error:
            //Dclient.ApiKey = "YYYYY";
            //Dclient.UserIP = "ZZZZZ";

Error   3   'Google.API.Translate.TranslateClient' does not contain a definition for 'ApiKey' and no extension method 'ApiKey' accepting a first argument of type 'Google.API.Translate.TranslateClient' could be found (are `enter code here`you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
even though the library is there and intellisense is showing me the property.

What else can I do?

Comment: Use the latest .Net client.

Comment: The latest client's GoogleClient base class *does* have a public ApiKey property...